# Laravel eloquent with relations taking huge amount of time to execute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

We have a model called **SentMessage** and we have defined a relation called **received_message_user**  (table: received_messages_users) on this model. There is another model called **ReceivedMessage** (table: received_messages_users) on which we have defined **additional_info** and  **list_member** relations.

For a particular id, let’s say 429189, we ran the following Laravel code. The time taken to execute it was around **~96 sec** which is very huge. It tries to fetch 39186 records along with the mentioned relations from the SentMessage model. The SQL queries are not taking much time but when they are written in the following manner they are taking very huge time. The following code can be written in Query builder but the issue is how to write ‘with’ functionality in query builder.

Can someone help me optimise this issue?

```
$sent = SentMessage::find($id);

$result = $sent
    ->received_message_user()->select('id', 'list_members_id', 'linked_sent_messages_id', 'read', 'read_snippet', 'date_received')
    ->with('additional_info:received_messages_table, message_id, online_notification_status, online_notification_sent_at, notification_delivered_at, online_notification_failure_reason')
    ->with('list_member:id,list_username')
    ->get();
```

Comment: what are your indexes ? on wich columns ?

Comment: **SentMessage** has indexes on message_text_id, conversation_id, (sender_user_id, message_for_list_id), sender_list_members_id
**additional_info** has index on (received_messages_table, message_id)
**ReceivedMessage** has indexes on receiver_id, linked_sent_messages_id, conversation_id, date_received, message_for_list_id, list_members_id

Comment: so you're sure the foreign keys are well indexed ?

Comment: Yes. The sql queries are not taking much time like I said but when used with eloquent functionality like **with** it is taking time